# Trouble importing local package

Tags: go

I've decided to try breaking my project into a MVC type view, so to start I wanted to put all my routing into a controller folder and I put my database connection into another folder titled db.

I can't figure out how to make the database connection work smoothly. Back when all of the files were in my `package main` I just called `InitDb()` in main and in all of my other files in the main package I had access to the db variable. Now that I made db it's down package and imported it, nothing is recognized.

I also don't know where to call `InitDb()` and `defer db.Close()` anymore since it's not all in main.

db/db.go

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
)

var db *sql.DB

const (
    dbhost = "localhost"
    dbuser = "root"
    dbpass = "password"
    dbname = "user"
)

func InitDb() {
    var err error

    connectionString := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@/%s", dbuser, dbpass, dbname)

    db, err = sql.Open("mysql", connectionString)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    err = db.Ping()

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("Successfully connected!")
}
```

controllers/index.go

```
package controllers

import (
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "db"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"

)

func TestHandler(r *mux.Router)
    r.HandleFunc("/index", test).Methods("GET")
}

func test(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // database undefined
    err := database.QueryRow("some sql statement")

    CheckErr(err)
}
```

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()

    controllers.TestHandler(r)

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe("localhost:8000", r))
}
```

Comment: Read [How to Write Go Code](https://golang.org/doc/code.html). The document shows how to create a library package and use it from the main package.

Comment: @CeriseLimón I read that, that's how I came to my current structure with every other importing working fine except for the database package.

Comment: @CeriseLimón If I just export db to main, controllers doesn't know about db, or at least that's what VSCode tells me. Do I have to call `InitDb()` from every package I use the database in now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not required it is a good idea to have the package name be the same as the folder in which it lives, so either do:

`db/db.go`

```
package db

// ...
```

Or do:

`database/db.go`

```
package database

// ...
```

I would not recommend mixing the two.

---

You can have your database package export a `Close` function and have main call it when it's done.

`database/db.go`

```
package database

import (
    "fmt"
    "database/sql"
)

var db *sql.DB

func Close() {
    db.Close()
}

// ...
```

`main.go`

```
package main

import "database"

func main() {
    defer database.Close()

    // ...
}
```

Or just don't close it in this case. When main exits the `*sql.DB` does not stay alive outside your program, it will not take up connection slots if the program is not running. Closing makes sense only if you're using multiple instances of `*sql.DB` and there is danger that they will start blocking while waiting for a connection. If you have only one that's shared by the whole program then you should be ok not calling defer close.

Comment: Oh I get it now, I was confusing about exporting functions but your simple explanation clears it up for me. Also thank you for the package naming tips, I'll have to rename the database one to match the folder.

Comment: Another question though, do I have to call `InitDb()` in every package I use the database?

Comment: @Mr.Smithyyy you don't have to, and you shouldn't so make sure you call it only once, because calling it multiple times is pointless and could actually cause "too many connections open" error, I think. You can call `InitDb` either from main, or inside the `database` package using the [init func](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#init).

Comment: thanks! I noticed when making queries currently from the controller I have to use `err := database.db.QueryRow` or `err := db.db.QueryRow`. I assume this is because of the global `db` variable in my database package but is there a way to make it so that it's just `database.QueryRow` or just `db.QueryRow`?

Comment: You can do that just like with the `Close` example, wrap every method on db you want to use in a function that's exported by the package.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks again for all of the help. Your explanations helped me understand all this much better than the documentation.